# Why is this function not returning the correct value?

Tags: c++, windows

I've made a function that converts an integer input into another integer, which it returns. Specifically, it takes in a console color, and returns a corresponding color which has the same background as the input, but with a white character.

This function always returns 255. What's going wrong?

```
int convertColorToPlayerColor(int color)
{
    int playerColor = 0;

    if (color <= 15)
        playerColor = 15;

    else if ((color > 15) && (color <= 31))
        playerColor = 31;

    else if ((color > 31) && (color <= 47))
        playerColor = 47;

    else if ((color > 47) && (color <= 63))
        playerColor = 63;

    else if ((color > 63) && (color <= 79))
        playerColor = 79;

    else if ((color > 79) && (color <= 95))
        playerColor = 95;

    else if ((color > 95) && (color <= 111))
        playerColor = 111;

    else if ((color > 111) && (color <= 127))
        playerColor = 127;

    else if ((color > 127) && (color <= 143))
        playerColor = 159;

    else if ((color > 159) && (color <= 175))
        playerColor = 175;

    else if ((color > 175) && (color <= 191))
        playerColor = 191;

    else if ((color > 191) && (color <= 207))
        playerColor = 207;

    else if ((color > 207) && (color <= 223))
        playerColor = 223;

    else if ((color > 223) && (color <= 239))
        playerColor = 239;

    else if (color > 239);
        playerColor = 255;

    return playerColor;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon:

```
else if (color > 239);    // <--- the semicolon
```

The extra semicolon gets parsed as the "then" part of an empty `if` statement. This effectively turns your function into

```
[ a long-winded if-else statement ]

playerColor = 255;

return playerColor;
```

Comment: Oh wow, I feel really dumb. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Aside that you have extra semicolon, you can make your function way simpler using `return` inside `if` and removing redundant checks:

```
   if (color <= 15)
      return 15;

   if (color <= 31) // no need to check color > 15
      return 31;

   if (color <= 47) // no need to check color > 31
      return 47;
   ...
   return 255; // no need for if (color > 239)
```

Also you can do binary lookup instead of linear check:

```
int convertColorToPlayerColor(int color)
{
     static std::vector<int> v { 15, 31, 47, 63, 79, 95, 111, 127, 143, 175, 191, 207, 223, 239 };
     auto it = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), color );
     return it == v.end() ? 255 : *it;
}
```

this will not only make it more effective and shorter, but make it less error prone (as you do not have to repeat numbers more than once). Just keep in mind that values in vector have to be in sorted order.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.